# Realizar una peticion get de una etiqueta select en django

Tags: django, django-forms

View

```
 def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = []
        code_card = self.request.GET.get("code", None)
        name_card = self.request.GET.get("brand", None)
        vip_card = self.request.GET("vip_select", None)
```

Template

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Vip</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="vip_select">
     <option value=true>Si</option>
     <option value=false>NO</option>
     </select>
```

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'QueryDict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error en esta parte de tu código:

```
vip_card = self.request.GET("vip_select", None)
```

Estás llamando a `GET` como si fuera una función. Tienes que hacerlo como has hecho las anteriores:

```
vip_card = self.request.GET.get("vip_select", None)
```

Por cierto, no es necesario que uses `None` cuando usas `dict.get` ya que ese es el varlor retornado por defecto:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    queryset = []
    code_card = self.request.GET.get("code")
    name_card = self.request.GET.get("brand")
    vip_card = self.request.GET.get("vip_select")
```